# My jQuery script makes always the first <select> look like focused when not

Tags: jquery, html, focus, this

Thing is, no matter which `<select>` I'm clicking, it always looks like the first one gets focused when actually the second one isn't.

The code works, but I want to implement the `$(this)` thing so the button I press is the one who must look focused, and I can't figure how to do it.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/TeNaf/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all `<div>`s with the same `ID`. You should not duplicate the `ID`s. They should be unique. And also, a `<label>` cannot have a `<div>` inside it.

Since you are using `$("#select")`, it selects only the first `<div>`. Make sure your `ID`s are unique and try it. This code works for you:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('select').focus( function(){
        $(this).closest("div").addClass('selected');
    });
    $('select').focusout( function(){
        $(this).closest("div").removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/TeNaf/2/

Comment: Thanks!

Yea I thought I was going to use only one select, then I decided to add another one and forgot the ID detail..